# Laravel delete item from overview

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of my DamagePoint model that I display in a table, my goal is to have a delete button for every item so that you can delete an item from the table.

I have a little problem where I can't seem to get my delete route working.
I get the following error:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function

Here is my route

```
Route::delete('pointdelete', 'DamagePointController@delete');
```

Here is my form

```
<?php echo Form::open(['url' => '/pointdelete', 'method' => 'delete']) ?>
    <?php echo Form::submit('X'); ?>
<?php echo Form::close() ?>
```

Here is my controller method

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $todo = DamagePoint::findOrFail($id);
     $todo->delete();

    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `delete` method use an `$id` parameter.
So your route need to handle it !

Try something like that :

**Route**

```
Route::delete('pointdelete/{id}', 'DamagePointController@delete');
```

**View**

Replace `$yourId` by the way you are getting your id

```
<?php echo Form::open(['url' => '/pointdelete/'.$yourId, 'method' => 'delete']) ?>
    <?php echo Form::submit('X'); ?>
<?php echo Form::close() ?>
```